# SQLite3 if exists add else increment

Tags: python, database, sqlite, discord.py, pycord

I'm trying to write a query for sqlite3 to check if a discordID exists in my database and increment the associated count variable if it exists and if not it should add a new row with that discordID and its associated count increased by one.

```
crs.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO {0} (discordID,count) VALUES ({1},1) UPDATE {0} SET count = count + 1 WHERE discordID = {1};".format(tableName,user))
```

I tried this query (where user is an input discordID) however I keep getting the error:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "UPDATE": syntax error

and I would like to know why this happening and how it can be fixed or if there's a better way to be doing this.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is an [`UPSERT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html). This allows you to specify an `ON CONFLICT` clause that will be executed if the `INSERT` would violate a constraint.

Applied to your query, it should look something like this:

```py
crs.execute("INSERT INTO {0} (discordID,count) VALUES ({1},1) ON CONFLICT(discordID) DO UPDATE SET count = count + 1;".format(tableName,user))
```

---

On a side note: you should avoid inserting user-generated content directly into your database and/or query strings. If you need to store user-generated inputs, look into using [prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp), otherwise you'll be vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)